# How to minification of group of string data in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uglifyjs

This is my code, i tried the following code but not working

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var result = UglifyJS.minify("Hello world @123;", { fromString: true });
console.log(result.code);
```

In the above code i am using UglifyJs. but i got error like `require is undefined`. i want to minimize the above string by using angularjs.

Comment: To use `require` you probably want to use a module loader like browserify. Also.. what does it mean to minify a string? What could the output possibly be?

Answer (score 1):

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
```

This code get the uglify-js and assign it to variable.

The error `require is undefined` is possible because of not inserting `requirejs` in your project.

Install `requirejs` using npm in your project directory

```
$ npm install --save bower-requirejs
```

Check more details on : https://github.com/yeoman/bower-requirejs

**Notes**:

UglifyJS is a JavaScript parser, minifier, compressor or beautifier toolkit.
It is not used to minifying string.

Below is basic example which has `javascript` code not **string**.

```
var result = UglifyJS.minify("var b = function () {};", {fromString: true});
```

Comment: i installed bower-requirejs and i injected bower-requirejs again it will throw same error 'require is undefined'

Comment: this is my code:    var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
     
           var result = UglifyJS.minify("var b = function () {};", { fromString: true });

Comment: Got your issue. You are trying to minify from client side but above code work for server...For client side, use following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424728/uglifyjs-on-client-side-javascript-or-an-alternative-parser)